# how to create uefi bootable image from bzimage (custom kernal)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, buildroot, uefi

for my project i have useb build-root to create a custom Linux kernel using menuconfig. i got my custom kernel image as bzimage file and root file directory as .tar image. i have built the kernel for x86 archetecture , Intel atom processor.

what i needed is to create a Linux OS .efi bootable image so that i can install the OS and try to test it .

i have tried copying the kernel image to /dev/sda1/EFI/ folder  and renaming it to bzimage.efi and creating a boot entry for it but it didnt work out. it couldnt read the file format.

can you pleas point me to the right direction or some tutorial to create the os image.

Comment: Did you enable the `CONFIG_EFI_STUB` option?

Comment: i couldnt find that option in menu config. am i looking in the wrong place. it should be enabled before building the kernel right?

Comment: Yes, it's a compile time option, under *Processor type and features* and *EFI runtime services support*.

Comment: but that option is not there. im using buildroot tool to build is. it dosent show any option like that

Comment: Are you running the Buildroot menuconfig, or the Linux kernel menuconfig ? If you're using Buildroot, running "make menuconfig" runs the Buildroot configuration tool. If you want to configure the Linux kernel in the context of Buildroot, you have to run "make linux-menuconfig"